# How many calories are burned by lifting 80 kilos once?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, estimation, unit-conversion, lift

After some calculations i figured it was something like 192 kilocalories but it sounds a bit too much so im not sure if i did the right calculations. What i did was calculate the work and then convert the Joules to Calories.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from Joules to calories involves a "little" calorie.  The capitalized form of "Calorie" (which I just did) is usually indicative of a food calorie, which is 1000 "little" calories.  This, of course, means that you need to be VERY particular on whether or not you capitalize the word "calorie".  Obviously, this nomenclature is ambiguous, but it exists in many text books, so it would not be easy to change every occurrence of "Calorie" to "kcal".

Comment: oh um what i meant was kcal sorry im still in lyceum didnt know theres a difference :p well what i converted was kilojoules to kilocalories

Comment: and how many joules did you have?  One small calorie is approximately 4.2 joules

Comment: 800 joules and used an online convertor well what i converted was 800kilojoules to kcal because 800 joules to kcal was something like 0.192 kcal, also lyceum is the equivelant of 10th-12th grade :p just wanted to point that out